# Android Databases-Cursor Returns Error

Tags: android, database, android-cursor

I am entirely new to Android and java.  Have worked in vb.net before.  I am trying to create an Android version of a vb.net app.  The database functions in Android are killing me.  Here is a short description of what I need to do.
- Create an "item" database with individual records for items.  I will need to add, update, delete, and retrieve data from these records.
- Create an "environment" database housing environmental variables (temperature, elevation, etc., and which item is currently being used from the "item" database.  I will need to update this record.

I have looked at several tutorials, and have tried to mimic them.  All seems correct in my code, but I get errors with the cursor function specifically (other errors too, but this seems to be the root of it).

To get me started around the problem, let's start with the environment database.  I created an SQLHelper, Database Manager, and an Activity to interact with it.  All three posed here.

I would like to have a more specific question, but after 3 days of trying to compare this to other posts, etc., I am completely lost.  Thanks to anyone who can help me!

```
HELPER
package com.becrs.becrsmobile;

import android.content.Context;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.util.Log;

public class EnvironmentSQLiteHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    public static final String TABLE_Environment = "envVar";
    public static final String ENV_COLUMN_ID = "_id";   
    public static final String COLUMN_elevation = "elevation";
  public static final String COLUMN_temperature = "temperature";
  public static final String COLUMN_ScopeIncrement = "ScopeIncrement";
  public static final String COLUMN_R1_Var = "R1_Var";
  public static final String COLUMN_R2_Var = "R2_Var";
  public static final String COLUMN_R3_Var = "R3_Var";
  public static final String COLUMN_R4_Var = "R4_Var";
  public static final String COLUMN_R5_Var = "R5_Var";
  public static final String COLUMN_R6_Var = "R6_Var";
  public static final String COLUMN_R7_Var = "R7_Var";
  public static final String COLUMN_R8_Var = "R8_Var";
  public static final String COLUMN_R9_Var = "R9_Var";
  public static final String COLUMN_MaxRange_Var = "MaxRange_Var";
  public static final String COLUMN_currentCartridge = "currentCartridge";

  private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "environmentdb.db";
  private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

  // Database creation sql statement
  private static final String DATABASE_CREATE = "create table "
      + TABLE_Environment + " (" + ENV_COLUMN_ID + " integer primary key autoincrement not null," 
      + COLUMN_elevation + " INTEGER, "
      + COLUMN_ScopeIncrement  + " REAL, "
      + COLUMN_R1_Var  + " INTEGER, "
      + COLUMN_R2_Var  + " INTEGER, "
      + COLUMN_R3_Var  + " INTEGER, "
      + COLUMN_R4_Var  + " INTEGER, "
      + COLUMN_R5_Var  + " INTEGER, "
      + COLUMN_R6_Var  + " INTEGER, "
      + COLUMN_R7_Var  + " INTEGER, "
      + COLUMN_R8_Var  + " INTEGER, "
      + COLUMN_R9_Var  + " INTEGER, "
      + COLUMN_MaxRange_Var  + " INTEGER, "
      + COLUMN_currentCartridge  + " INTEGER"
      + ");";

  public EnvironmentSQLiteHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
  }

  @Override
  public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase database) {
    database.execSQL(DATABASE_CREATE);
  }

  @Override
  public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    Log.w(EnvironmentSQLiteHelper.class.getName(),
        "Upgrading database from version " + oldVersion + " to "
            + newVersion + ", which will destroy all old data");
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_Environment);
    onCreate(db);
  }

} 

DATABASE MANAGER
package com.becrs.becrsmobile;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.SQLException;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.util.Log;

public class EnvironmentDataSource {

  // Database fields
  private SQLiteDatabase database;
  private EnvironmentSQLiteHelper dbHelper;
  private String[] allColumns = { 
      EnvironmentSQLiteHelper.ENV_COLUMN_ID,
      EnvironmentSQLiteHelper.COLUMN_elevation,
      EnvironmentSQLiteHelper.COLUMN_temperature,
      EnvironmentSQLiteHelper.COLUMN_ScopeIncrement,
      EnvironmentSQLiteHelper.COLUMN_R1_Var,
      EnvironmentSQLiteHelper.COLUMN_R2_Var,
      EnvironmentSQLiteHelper.COLUMN_R3_Var,
      EnvironmentSQLiteHelper.COLUMN_R4_Var,
      EnvironmentSQLiteHelper.COLUMN_R5_Var,
      EnvironmentSQLiteHelper.COLUMN_R6_Var,
      EnvironmentSQLiteHelper.COLUMN_R7_Var,
      EnvironmentSQLiteHelper.COLUMN_R8_Var,
      EnvironmentSQLiteHelper.COLUMN_R9_Var,
      EnvironmentSQLiteHelper.COLUMN_MaxRange_Var,
      EnvironmentSQLiteHelper.COLUMN_currentCartridge,
      };

  public EnvironmentDataSource(Context context) {
    dbHelper = new EnvironmentSQLiteHelper(context);
  }

  public void open() throws SQLException {
    database = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
  }

  public void close() {
    dbHelper.close();
  }
  public Environment updateEnvironment(int elevation, int temperature, Double ScopeIncrement, int R1, int R2, int R3, int R4, int R5, int R6, int R7, int R8, int R9, int MaxRng, int currentCartridge) {
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(EnvironmentSQLiteHelper.COLUMN_elevation, elevation);
        values.put(EnvironmentSQLiteHelper.COLUMN_temperature, temperature);
        values.put(EnvironmentSQLiteHelper.COLUMN_ScopeIncrement, ScopeIncrement);
        values.put(EnvironmentSQLiteHelper.COLUMN_R1_Var, R1);
        values.put(EnvironmentSQLiteHelper.COLUMN_R2_Var, R2);
        values.put(EnvironmentSQLiteHelper.COLUMN_R3_Var, R3);
        values.put(EnvironmentSQLiteHelper.COLUMN_R4_Var, R4);
        values.put(EnvironmentSQLiteHelper.COLUMN_R5_Var, R5);
        values.put(EnvironmentSQLiteHelper.COLUMN_R6_Var, R6);
        values.put(EnvironmentSQLiteHelper.COLUMN_R7_Var, R7);
        values.put(EnvironmentSQLiteHelper.COLUMN_R8_Var, R8);
        values.put(EnvironmentSQLiteHelper.COLUMN_R9_Var, R9);
        values.put(EnvironmentSQLiteHelper.COLUMN_MaxRange_Var, MaxRng);
        values.put(EnvironmentSQLiteHelper.COLUMN_currentCartridge, currentCartridge);
        long insertID;
        try {
            database.update(EnvironmentSQLiteHelper.TABLE_Environment, values, "_id = 0 ", allColumns);
            insertID = 0;
        } 
        catch (Exception e){
            insertID = database.insert(EnvironmentSQLiteHelper.TABLE_Environment, null, values);
        }
        Cursor cursor = database.query(EnvironmentSQLiteHelper.TABLE_Environment,
                allColumns, EnvironmentSQLiteHelper.ENV_COLUMN_ID + " = " + insertID, null,
                null, null, null, null);
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        Environment newEnvironment = cursorToEnvironment(cursor); 
        cursor.close();
        return newEnvironment;
      }

  public Environment getEnvironment() {
      Cursor cursor = null;
      try {  
          cursor = database.query(EnvironmentSQLiteHelper.TABLE_Environment,
                allColumns, EnvironmentSQLiteHelper.ENV_COLUMN_ID + " = 0", allColumns, null, null, null, null);
      }
      catch (SQLException e) 
    {
        Log.e("DB ERROR", e.toString());
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
        Environment environment = null;
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()){
            environment =  cursorToEnvironment(cursor);
        }
        cursor.close();
        return environment;
      }
  private Environment cursorToEnvironment(Cursor cursor) {
    Environment environment = new Environment();
    environment.setelevation(cursor.getInt(0));
    environment.settemperature(cursor.getInt(1));
    environment.setlongRangeScopeIncrement(cursor.getDouble(2));
    environment.setR1_Var(cursor.getInt(3));
    environment.setR2_Var(cursor.getInt(4));
    environment.setR3_Var(cursor.getInt(5));
    environment.setR4_Var(cursor.getInt(6));
    environment.setR5_Var(cursor.getInt(7));
    environment.setR6_Var(cursor.getInt(8));
    environment.setR7_Var(cursor.getInt(9));
    environment.setR8_Var(cursor.getInt(10));
    environment.setR9_Var(cursor.getInt(11));
    environment.setMaxRange_Var(cursor.getInt(12));
    environment.setcurrentCartridge(cursor.getString(13));
    return environment;
  }
} 

INTERFACE ACTIVITY
package com.becrs.becrsmobile;


import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;


public class EnvironmentEditActivity extends Activity 
{
    private EnvironmentDataSource datasource;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_editenvironment);   
        datasource = new EnvironmentDataSource(this);
        datasource.open();
        Button save = (Button)findViewById(R.id.ButtonSaveEnvironment);       
        save.setOnClickListener(startsaveListener);
        Environment environment = datasource.getEnvironment();
        String TempVal;
        TextView mTextView;
        TempVal = Integer.toString(environment.getelevation());
        mTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.input_Elevation);
        mTextView.setText(TempVal);
        TempVal = Integer.toString(environment.gettemperature());
        mTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.input_Temperature);
        mTextView.setText(TempVal);
        TempVal = Double.toString(environment.getlongRangeScopeIncrement());
        mTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.input_ClickIncrement);
        mTextView.setText(TempVal);
        TempVal = Integer.toString(environment.getR1_Var());
        mTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.input_R1);
        mTextView.setText(TempVal);
        TempVal = Integer.toString(environment.getR2_Var());
        mTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.input_R2);
        mTextView.setText(TempVal);
        TempVal = Integer.toString(environment.getR3_Var());
        mTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.input_R3);
        mTextView.setText(TempVal);
        TempVal = Integer.toString(environment.getR4_Var());
        mTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.input_R4);
        mTextView.setText(TempVal);
        TempVal = Integer.toString(environment.getR5_Var());
        mTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.input_R5);
        mTextView.setText(TempVal);
        TempVal = Integer.toString(environment.getR6_Var());
        mTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.input_R6);
        mTextView.setText(TempVal);
        TempVal = Integer.toString(environment.getR7_Var());
        mTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.input_R7);
        mTextView.setText(TempVal);
        TempVal = Integer.toString(environment.getR8_Var());
        mTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.input_R8);
        mTextView.setText(TempVal);
        TempVal = Integer.toString(environment.getR9_Var());
        mTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.input_R9);
        mTextView.setText(TempVal);
        TempVal = Integer.toString(environment.getMaxRange_Var());
        mTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.input_MaxRng);
        mTextView.setText(TempVal);
    }    
        private OnClickListener startsaveListener = new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                EditText elevation = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.input_Elevation);
                int elevationVal = Integer.parseInt(elevation.getText().toString());
                EditText temperature = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.input_Temperature);
                int temperatureVal = Integer.parseInt(temperature.getText().toString());
                EditText clickIncrement = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.input_ClickIncrement);
                Double clickIncrementVal = Double.parseDouble(clickIncrement.getText().toString());
                EditText R1 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.input_R1);
                int R1Val = Integer.parseInt(R1.getText().toString());
                EditText R2 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.input_R2);
                int R2Val = Integer.parseInt(R2.getText().toString());
                EditText R3 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.input_R3);
                int R3Val = Integer.parseInt(R3.getText().toString());
                EditText R4 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.input_R4);
                int R4Val = Integer.parseInt(R4.getText().toString());
                EditText R5 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.input_R5);
                int R5Val = Integer.parseInt(R5.getText().toString());
                EditText R6 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.input_R6);
                int R6Val = Integer.parseInt(R6.getText().toString());
                EditText R7 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.input_R7);
                int R7Val = Integer.parseInt(R7.getText().toString());
                EditText R8 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.input_R8);
                int R8Val = Integer.parseInt(R8.getText().toString());
                EditText R9 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.input_R9);
                int R9Val = Integer.parseInt(R9.getText().toString());
                EditText MaxRng = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.input_MaxRng);
                int MaxRngVal = Integer.parseInt(MaxRng.getText().toString());
                int RecordNum = 0;
                datasource.updateEnvironment(elevationVal, temperatureVal, clickIncrementVal, R1Val, R2Val, R3Val, R4Val, R5Val, R6Val, R7Val, R8Val, R9Val, MaxRngVal, RecordNum);
                setResult(RESULT_OK);
                finish();
            }
        };


    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
      datasource.open();
      super.onResume();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
      datasource.close();
      super.onPause();
    }

}
```

ENVIRONMENT OBJECT

```
package com.becrs.becrsmobile;

public class Environment {
    private static int elevation;
    private static int temperature;
    private static Double longRangeScopeIncrement;
    private static int R0_Var;
    private static int R1_Var;
    private static int R2_Var;
    private static int R3_Var;
    private static int R4_Var;
    private static int R5_Var;
    private static int R6_Var;
    private static int R7_Var;
    private static int R8_Var;
    private static int R9_Var;
    private static int MaxRange_Var;
    private static int currentCartridge;
    public static int getelevation()  {
        return elevation;
    }
    public void setelevation(int elevation) {
        Environment.elevation = elevation;
    }
    public static int gettemperature()  {
        return temperature;
    }
    public void settemperature(int temperature) {
        Environment.temperature = temperature;
    }
    public static double getlongRangeScopeIncrement()  {
        return longRangeScopeIncrement;
    }
    public void setlongRangeScopeIncrement(Double longRangeScopeIncrement) {
        Environment.longRangeScopeIncrement = longRangeScopeIncrement;
    }
    public static int getR0_Var()  {
        return R0_Var;
    }
    public void setR0_Var(int R0_Var) {
        Environment.R0_Var = R0_Var;
    }
    public static int getR1_Var()  {
        return R1_Var;
    }
    public void setR1_Var(int R1_Var) {
        Environment.R1_Var =R1_Var;
    }
    public static int getR2_Var()  {
        return R2_Var;
    }
    public void setR2_Var(int R2_Var) {
        Environment.R2_Var = R2_Var;
    }
    public static int getR3_Var()  {
        return R3_Var;
    }
    public void setR3_Var(int R3_Var) {
        Environment.R3_Var = R3_Var;
    }
    public static int getR4_Var()  {
        return R4_Var;
    }
    public void setR4_Var(int R4_Var) {
        Environment.R4_Var = R4_Var;
    }
    public static int getR5_Var()  {
        return R5_Var;
    }
    public void setR5_Var(int R5_Var) {
        Environment.R5_Var = R5_Var;
    }
    public static int getR6_Var()  {
        return R6_Var;
    }
    public void setR6_Var(int R6_Var) {
        Environment.R6_Var = R6_Var;
    }
    public static int getR7_Var()  {
        return R7_Var;
    }
    public void setR7_Var(int R7_Var) {
        Environment.R7_Var = R7_Var;
    }
    public static int getR8_Var()  {
        return R8_Var;
    }
    public void setR8_Var(int R8_Var) {
        Environment.R8_Var = R8_Var;
    }
    public static int getR9_Var()  {
        return R9_Var;
    }
    public void setR9_Var(int R9_Var) {
        Environment.R9_Var = R9_Var;
    }
    public static int getMaxRange_Var()  {
        return MaxRange_Var;
    }
    public void setMaxRange_Var(int MaxRange_Var) {
        Environment.MaxRange_Var = MaxRange_Var;
    }
    public static int getcurrentCartridge()  {
        return currentCartridge;
    }
    public void setcurrentCartridge(int currentCartridge) {
        Environment.currentCartridge = currentCartridge;
    }
}
```

Comment: What you do try to query in getEnvironment? Your query is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

First Create Environment Object, because it is where your sqlliteopen helper instantiate with context

```
Environment environment=new Environment(context);
```

And then

```
 Environment env= environment.getEnvironment();
```

Comment: I did create the Environment object (forgot to put it above, now added).  Where do I insert what you are saying?  In the HELPER code?  Thank you!!

Comment: @ShannonHinkle you need to getEnvironement from Environment Object, I forgot to mention in the answer, check edit

Comment: Thanks!  I'm still trying to figure out where I need to put what you suggest.